# Function spaces that are not vector spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, topological-vector-spaces

Consider the problem of minimizing $$J(u) = \int_0^1 -\log u(x) - \log(1-u(x)) \, dx,$$
where the logarithm is defined as $\log(\xi) = -\infty$ when $\xi\leq 0$. Note that the function $\xi \to -\log(\xi)-\log(1-\xi)$ is convex with a minimum at $\xi = 1/2$ so the natural domain of definition of $J(u)$ is $$D = \{u(x) \; : \; u(x) \text{ is measurable and } 0 < u(x) < 1 \}.$$
I'm interested in doing functional analysis on sets like $D$. (For example, $J(u)$ could have $u'(x)$ in its definition instead of $u(x)$, and then one would pair this with boundary conditions to study certain nonlinear PDEs.)

Is there a "functional analysis" for such domains? For example, it would be natural to define a metric from $J(u)$ (since it is convex) and obtain a unique minimizer, if not in $D$, in some completion of $D$.

Comment: Banach manifolds are often used for similar purposes

Comment: Minimising functionals over an admissible set of functions which satisfy some inequality (such as $D$) leads to an obstacle-type problem. The most classic example is when $J$ is the Dirichlet energy and $D=\{u \in H^1_0 \, \vert \, u>0\}$. You could have a look at “An Introduction to Variational Inequalities and Their Applications” by Kinderlehrer and Stampacchia.